# CSS Alignment does not work as it is supposed to be

Tags: css, alignment, moodle

I have faced with a problem for the same page with the same data but different templates which is used my PHP framework moodle.
The data and mustache files are identical. There is just one difference as far as I can see, it is CSS. 
Maybe someone can see the error which I can't see from below screenshots.
Please guide me if some more details are needed to figure out the problem.
[This is the problematic display][1]
[This is the screen how it is supposed to be][2]

```
 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOJzZ.png
 [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1pEU.png
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="display: flex">
  <left-arrow/>
  <div style="flex-grow: 1">
    <field/>
  </div>
  <right-arrow/>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: It's better now. But still needs to improve in the light of these explanations. 
The situation after your solution applied 
https://i.imgur.com/WQ4d9jo.png
When the screen widened the arrows disappeared 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDP7Q.png 
The screen should be displayed like this when widened 
https://i.imgur.com/rPMCInK.png